# OsTicket Blank Page after install (no data received)

Tags: php, mysql, osticket

I am trying to install osticket to my server (PHP 5.3, MYsql >5.0).

After I upload the 'upload' directory to my server, I go to mydomain.com/osticket and am taken to the install page. I fill out the form, and if I get no validation errors in the form, the page submits.

However, then I get an error (No data received in chrome) and if I refresh the page I am taking back to install.php to fill the form out again.

I should note that the app created tables in the database I gave it. I also enabled errors in bootstrap.php and I saw no errors there or in the error logs. I tried v 1.9.0 and 1.8.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please change "max_execution_time=30" to "max_execution_time=120" in       php.ini file

Answer (score 3):

Increase the "MAX_EXECUTION_TIME" in the PHP.ini file of your web server installation.
I had the same problem and managed to resolve changing it from 30 to 180.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it works after changing max_execution_time from 30 to 120